# Is there a list of methodologies ordered by activity

Tags: methodology

*NOTE: I'm not sure that this is on-topic, but let's try.*

#### Considerations

There are many methodologies, and these are tools for a PM. A PM that passes from the programming world, to the world of construction, it is probably oriented to apply tools he/she knows *(which operate in a specific environment)*.

#### Question

Leaving aside the advice you can get from those who have successfully used a methodology that was not created for a specific type of project (for example *coordinate the construction of an hotel using SCRUM*).

Where can I find a **list of methodologies** (*ie, Waterfall, ASD, ...*) or at least **list of approaches** (*id, Agile methodology, ...*), with its areas of use (not only for the computing world)?

Comment: I think the answer to this question resides in the actual Body of Knowledge of the discipline you want to relate to.

Comment: Gastón, you're absolutely right. As I commented to Marv, the attempt was to gain access to some research already advanced, maybe not for all disciplines _(which is certainly an exaggeration)_, but already advanced.

Comment: Good, may I ask what's the ultimate goal of your investigation? Perhaps it's something that might be useful to this community, rather than just "googling" about PM.

Comment: Gastón, my example was not so far from reality. I'm managing a project since the beginning of 2013, which includes not only software development, system integration, etc.. Together with structural architect, considering the complications had _(especially for the place where we are)_, we promised to design a tool that best suits our needs, that would be used during the second phase of the project. For this reason, comes the curiosity to learn more environments.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia is a good place to start, see the Project Management page here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management. This page contains a list of PM Methodologies and a discussion on the features of each

Comment: Thank you Marv, Google is certainly a resource for start this from scratch. Wikipedia, where I am collecting information from some days ago, it offers a good filter to what Google _picks up_ (which is probably all), but the work from scratch is very expensive. Mine was an attempt to find some study already advanced.

Answer (score 1):

### Areas of use is becoming fuzzier

Scrum was created for software development. [However, Jeff Sutherland, co-founder of Scrum is now talking about how Scrum is helping everything from Education to Agriculture to Government (first 30 seconds)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUaywvsfe78).

[PRINCE2 was created for managing IT projects. However, now it is the UK government de facto project management standard for all public projects.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRINCE2)

Broadly speaking, the methodologies can be grouped into predictive and adaptive planning ones. PMBOK, PRINCE2 and Waterfall will go into the predictive bucket. Agile mehtodologies including Scrum and XP will go into the adaptive bucket.  (By the way, I am using the term 'methodology' loosely. Scrum is a framework, PMBOK is a standard.)

[image: Stacey Complexity Matrix]

Referring to the Stacey Complexity Matrix, Software Development, New Product Development and Applied R&D Projects all belong in the complicated or complex category. Use an adaptive planning methodology for these. Frequent inspection and adaptation are key here.

Construction and Engineering projects benefit from clearly agreed requirements and well established technology. Predictive planning works better for these. Good upfront planning is key here.

Comment: Ashok, thanks for the reply. Yes!, I am convinced that we _(say experts in agile)_, we can run a restaurant with SCRUM. But I am also convinced that anyone who runs successfully a restaurant, he/she is not interested in SCRUM. This because their methodology works. In my opinion, _sectors_ that want/change methodologies do it because they understand they have in some way **poor results** (or they think these can be improved). I'm looking for a list of methodologies that are successful, in different areas (**considered as standards**), mostly to understand the benefits of these.

Comment: btw, Jeff's video is very interesting.